# Preserving and restoring application state in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, android-lifecycle, ios-lifecycle

In Prism for xamarin forms, How does the navigation stack is restored when application is resumed after got killed by OS?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Documentation/blob/master/docs/xamarin-forms/Application-Lifecycle-Management.md) you can check the official Prism documentation about Application Lifecycle Management.

The typical application lifecycle events are:

- **Initializing** - This happens the first time the app is launched.
- **Resuming** -  This happens every time we restore the app from the background after it has been suspended.
- **Sleeping** - This happens when the OS decides to freeze our app after it has gone in background

The methods:

```
  protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            // TODO: Refresh network data, perform UI updates, and reacquire resources like cameras, I/O devices, etc.

        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            base.OnSleep();

            // TODO: This is the time to save app data in case the process is terminated.
            // This is the perfect timing to release exclusive resources (camera, I/O devices, etc...)

        }
```

Facing this, you have methods that are called in each situation. You should override them and, depending on your needs, implement the requirements that you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I couldn't find a way to restore the navigation stack.